# How to select only part of BLOB column

Tags: sqlite

How can I select only 1kb from a BLOB field, in a SQLite Database?

I imagine it to be something like this

```
SELECT PART(`field_name`, startIndex, bytes) AS data FROM `table` ....
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [substr()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#substr):

> The substr(X,Y,Z) function returns a substring of input string X that begins with the Y-th character and which is Z characters long.
>   If X is a BLOB then the indices refer to bytes.