# Sqlite3 select range of bytes\chars from blob

Tags: sqlite, blob

I have hex blob row 12582912 bytes.
I need select range of bytes from this row

I have tried:

```
select substr(hex(row), 1, 5242880) from table where id=id;
```

where 1 is start byte, and 5424880 - end byte. It works, but it's slow.

Are there other ways to get a range of bytes from hex blob in sqlite?

Comment: Try doing the substring on the blob itself: `hex(substr(row, 1, end_interval))`. Or use the incremental IO interface.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select only part of BLOB column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27802393/how-to-select-only-part-of-blob-column)

Comment: Thanks, this > hex(substr(row, 1, end_interval)) way is the best, 10 000 000 Bytes read at 120-220ms.